# How to create a Graph from a text file

Tags: java, file, graph

I'm trying to create a Graph from a text file formatted (Vertex a) (Vertex b) (Edge between the two) but I'm stuck on how to take the names of vertex a and b and make those the names of the two vertices if that makes any sense. I know its got to be easy but I'm hitting a wall. I've tried things like:

```
Vertex s.next() = new Vertex();
```

or saving the string into a variable and using it,

```
Vertex v1 = new Vertex();
```

I've looked around and cannot seem to find an example close enough to my issue to help me solve it.

Comment: Try this: [graph-data-structure-tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/377473-graph-data-structure-tutorial/)

Comment: If I get your question correctly, you want to store the vertices by name. Ofcourse you could store the name in the object, however you could also make use of a HashMap<String, Vertex>. that way you can for instance get the vertex with the name 'a'.